# ArrayFormula cell part replacement for an array

Tags: google-sheets

Ref sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1scZ_jlw6Wx1xH3gQ_z9rBAadyw6WxqcbFk10VQIDjHk/edit#gid=226679863).

Have column that can contain empty cells or CSV strings. 
Need to map the CSV string parts (VLOOKUP) and rebuild the column with the replaced parts in one formula.

In the linked sheet, I have managed to do it for single cells. But would like a single ArrayFormula that does it for all the values. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

In H3 I entered this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(substitute(trim(transpose(query(transpose(iferror(vlookup((split(A3:A, "|")),E1:F, 2, 0))),,rows(A3:A)))), " ", "|"))
```

If you need to deal with spaces, try:

```
=ArrayFormula(substitute(substitute(trim(transpose(query(transpose(iferror(vlookup((split(substitute(A3:A15, " ", "¬"), "|")),substitute(ThemeEn, " ", "¬") , 2, 0))),,rows(A3:A15)))), " ", "|"), "¬", " "))
```

Comment: There is one issue, which was not accounted for in the sample data sheet. If the mapped (VLOOKUP'ed) value has a *space* it fouls up with the #space# introduced by QUERY when header rows are concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

In cell **I2** I have entered my solution:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(ArrayFormula(JOIN("|",VLOOKUP(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,IF(A2:A15="","~",A2:A15)),"|"),{ThemeEn;"~","~"},2,FALSE))),"~|","`"),"|~","`"),"|`","``"),"`",TRUE,FALSE))
```

- I add one row to the map to handled empty rows : "~" -> "~"
- IF function within VLOOKUP replaces empty cells with "~"
- Rebuilding the column is messy with 3 SUBSTITUTE statements :: can this be made simpler?